# Capturing the GUID of a process started at runtime

Tags: c#, guid

I am not sure how to get the GUID of  a process I start at runtime.  So for example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\MyDir";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "MyApp.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "E F G H";
proc.Start();
```

I have found this code in another thread that exposes the GUID of the current app:

```
var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
var attribute = (GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
var id = attribute.Value;
```

but I am unsure how to apply this to `proc` or if there is an attribute in proc that will show its GUID.  How can I get the GUID of `proc`?

Answer (score 0):

Processes don't have GUIDs.

You can retrieve an attribute from a known class in a managed assembly using Reflection:

```
Assembly.Load(path).GetType("Namespace.Type")
                   .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]
```

Comment: The code you gave is not what the OP want, it's used to get attribute of some type in the assembly.

Comment: @KingKing Can you clarify? This looks to answer the question to me. It also explains the processes don't have a GUID assigned to them.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead the first may look right but the code is obviously used to get GUID attribute of some type, I think the OP may want to mean he wants to get the GUID of the **exe file** which is also an **assembly**, so why doesn't it have a GUID? Of course it's not process he meant, he might mean the **exe file**

Comment: @KingKing: The answer is correct. *Proceses* (which is what the poster asked about, and what `System.Diagnostics.Process` returns) do not have GUIDs. There's no indication whatsoever that the process being started is a managed app or not, and the question clearly asks about a process.

Comment: @KenWhite **I did not say the answer was wrong**, I just wanted to mean that the code is **unnecessary**, don't you think so? It's for a type so why posting it? to make the answer **long enough**? even posting a comment is better with just the first line.

Comment: Yes it is an exe file.  In my spesific case, MyApp.exe is calling itself.  The app is using Enterprise Library for logging and the log generated in the recursive execution cannot log to the same log file, so it created a new log file with the GUID of the creating application in its file name.  Rather than use a different logging system, I would just like to log the GUID of the exe that is started as a reference.

Comment: @Justin204 looks like you can use the `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFile` to get an instance of the corresponding assembly of your physical exe file and use that instance in your code (replacing `typeof(Program).Assembly`)

Comment: While I am sure this is pointing me in the right direction, I seem to lack the savvy to pull it all together.  The code I produce either causes an error, won't start a new copy of the exe or it will, but continues to return the guid of the original exe and not the second exe.  I know it is the 1st guid because my original LogFile contains "df5b1393-cba3-4641-b735-d03e6377c47f" but the file name of the second log file (which has the guid of exe that created in it's name) is "03d3085d-c4f8-4387-ab5f-388880a1e185LogFile".

Comment: @Justin204: It sounds like you're trying to load two versions of the same assembly.  That's an extremely complicated topic.  Try `ReflectionOnlyLoad()`.  And note that none of this has anything to do with starting a process.

Comment: Yes, it occurs to me that perhaps I get the same guid because it is the same exe, and the other guid is coming from Enterprise Library.  When I get a moment, I will try and call a completely separate exe rather than the same exe and see if that is in fact working - then tackle the more complex issue of loading and uniquely identifying the same exe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the ID of the process, you can just get the property using `proc.Id`.

See the [Process.Id Property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That was where I started but the integer returned from proc.id is not what I needed.